# Trying to set up a "masked URL redirect" (that might not be the correct term)

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, cname

OK, what I want is, if a person types the URL "test.MyClientsDomain.net" they actually go to "MyCompanyDomain.com" (but the URL bar shows "test.MyClientsDomain.net").

Here is what I have done so far:

- We purchased a SSL from goDaddy that allows us to add multiple domains and both domains are on it.
- MyCompanyDomain.com is our main site, on a windows server at Rackspace that I have control over, and that works as expected
- I have MyClientsDomain.net registered at NameCheap, the DNS is hosted at a 3rd party (plesk server that I have control of)
- I have added a CNAME at the 3rd party DNS that points test.MyClientsDomain.net to MyCompanyDomain.com
- I have added the "zone" MyClientsDomain.net to the DNS at Rackspace and it points to the webserver's IP
- I have added a CNAME at the Rackspace DNS that points test.MyClientsDomain.net to MyCompanyDomain.com

But it's not working as I want, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "it's not working as I want..." is not a useful description of a problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - I guess I was hoping for a reply of instructions (or a link, I can't find anything helpful) that would tell me how to accomplish my goal. What IS happening is that going to the test.MyClientsDomain.net is pulling up an old domain that does have the same IP as MyCompanyDomain.com, which frankly just further confuses the issue. And regardless, when it gets there, the URL isn't "masked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, when you type `test.MyClientsDomain.net` in the browser, you want to be redirected to `MyCompanyDomain.com`, but the URL bar of the browser still displays `test.MyClientsDomain.net`.

In IIS, to achieve this effect you need to use the URL Rewrite module and configure proxy settings for ARR. If you have not installed the ARR module on IIS, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-arr/install-application-request-routing-version-2).

When you have two websites, the domain name of website 1 is bound to `MyCompanyDomain.com`, and the domain name of website 2 is bound to `test.MyClientsDomain.net`. If you want to achieve your needs, you need to create a rewrite rule on website 2. The following URL rewrite rule in the web.config can give you a reference:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test rule in website2" enabled="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://MyCompanyDomain.com" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Also, you need to select Application Request Routing Cache module at server level and select "Server Proxy Settings…" on the right tree node
, then check "Enable Proxy" and apply.

At this time, when you type `test.MyClientsDomain.net` in the browser, you will see that the page loads the content of the `MyCompanyDomain.com` website, and the URL bar still shows `test.MyClientsDomain.net`.

[image: image1]

Comment: The question says one website is hosted at Rackspace, the other on a 3rd party, is your solution working in that setup ?

Comment: @YurongDai - sorry for the delay in response, other projects jumped ahead of this one. If I am understanding correctly, I need to create test.MyClientsDomain.net in my IIS, even though the end result will be using "pages" from "MyCompanyDomain.com"

Comment: @yurongdai - that resolved it, but it was even simpler than that. I simply created a blank folder for the url in the wwwroot directory, created the site in IIS with no additional config, and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't mentionning the use of *Name Virtual Hosting* on MyCompanyDomain.com and for this reason you're ending serving that old domain matching the same IP.

*Name Virtual Hosting* allows one to publish multiple applications on the same IP, or to publish a very same application with different domain names (what you call "masking"). However for the latter to be completely transparent, nothing like a 301/302 Redirect from one domain to the another should be configure.

Have a look at how configuring [Configuring SSL Host Headers in IIS](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-7.htm).